# WCF Using net.tcp binding

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, net.tcp

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.  I'm attempting to host a WCF service which will use Windows security (net.tcp binding) on IIS7. The service I'm running is a very simple skeleton app, which works fine so far with HTTP and HTTPS.  (I've finally gotten HTTPS to work and I'm just trying to add another binding--NET.TCP.)

I've configured IIS to enable net.tcp: I added a net.tcp binding with Binding information "808:*".  My "Advanced Settings -> Enabled Protocols" field is set to "https,net.tcp".

The entire solution (contains the service application and a client app which consumes both http and https) can be found at http://petio.org/2011/06/29/MagicEightBall.zip.  In the service Web.config, a copy of which can be found at http://petio.org/2011/06/29/MagicEightBall/Web.config,

I have three endpoints: http, https, and net.tcp. Right now http and https are working properly, but I have the net.tcp endpoint commented out.  When I uncomment this, it breaks http and https, and then when I navigate to http://localhost/MagicEightBall/MagicEightBallService.svc, I see the error:

> The protocol 'net.tcp' is not
>   supported.

What am I doing wrong?  All code is posted on the above links, or you can navigate the solution via ftp://petio.org/2011/06/29/MagicEightBall/.

By the way, I've already activated 'Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation', and made sure the 'Net.Tcp Listener Adapter' service is running.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jay Sullivan

Comment: Shouldn't the uri to net tcp endpoint be net.tcp://localhost/MagicEightBall/MagicEightBallService.svc ?

Comment: It is.  But when I uncomment, it breaks everything else, so navigating to that http URI shows the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely an IIS issue - it's a bit tricky and unintuitive to get to work at first.

Read:

- [Configuring Internet Information Services 7.0 for Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675150.aspx)

and then:

- [How to: Install and Configure WCF Activation Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx)

Those steps are needed - if you do them correctly and in the right order, everything should work fine after that.

Comment: I went through the first link, still have same issue.  
For the second link: is it necessary to do this on the command line or can I do this through Edit Bindings and Advanced Settings in IIS?

Comment: @Notfed: no idea - I've always done it on the command line. Try it in the IIS Admin UI - if that doesn't work, try the command line .....

Comment: I was getting quickly discouraged because I did this and still saw the same error.  But after a computer restart, things appear to be working.  I think the first link is what fixed it, because I already had all those bindings through the UI.